# How to create a chooser that displays only apps that supports video calling ? In Android Kotlin project

Tags: android, kotlin

**Create chooser using intent in android kotlin, that displays only apps that supports video calling?**
eg : Skype, Whatsapp, Meet, Duo, Zoom etc...

**Usecase:** On click of a button need to display the chooser with all the video calling apps installed, and upon clicking on the displayed app in chooser user needs to be navigated to that app.

Tried below code, but it does not show all the video calling apps and also displaying some other apps which does not support video calling.

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

intent.type = "video/*"

val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, null)

try {
    context.startActivity(chooser)
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    // add error handling code
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  If you're calling someone, they're likely only on one of those things at most.  If you have their phone number, you're not going to want to call via zoom-  that's not ever going to work.  I think you need to explain your usecase better.

Comment: @GabeSechan, Usecase: On click of a button need to display the chooser with all the video calling apps installed, and upon clicking on the displayed app in chooser user needs to be navigated to that app.

Comment: My god... that is NOT called a use case. And you had already told that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Intent` structure that is guaranteed to identify all video calling apps (for whatever definition of "video calling" you happen to be considering) and ignore all non-video calling apps.

You are welcome to build your own list of package names/application IDs of "video calling" apps, put that list in your app (including in a `<queries>` element of your manifest), then [use `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` on `PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @CommonsWare for the solution.

Here is how to create custom chooser:

```
val videoCallingApps = listOf("com.whatsapp", "com.skype.raider", "us.zoom.videomeetings")
        val packageManager = packageManager

        val videoCallingAppIntents = mutableListOf<Intent>()
        for (packageName in videoCallingApps) {
            val launchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
            if (launchIntent != null) {
                videoCallingAppIntents.add(launchIntent)
            }
        }

        if (videoCallingAppIntents.isNotEmpty()) {
            val chooser = Intent.createChooser(
                videoCallingAppIntents.removeAt(0),
                null
            )
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, videoCallingAppIntents.toTypedArray())

            try {
               startActivity(chooser)
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                //Handle error
            }
        }
```

Add package inside AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <queries>
        <!-- Declare allowed queries for external apps -->
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
        <package android:name="com.skype.raider" />
        <package android:name="us.zoom.videomeetings" />
    </queries>
```